# What is happening when a jenga block tower wobbles?

Tags: kinematics, everyday-life, statics

Imagine I am 3/4's of the way through a [Jenga](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenga) wooden block game. I have a tower and it is starting to wobble.

To me it seems there are two possible causes for this:

- the wood is compressing and expanding, and the sum total of this makes the tower sway
- imperfections in the straightness and squareness of the wood are having a cumulative effect to make the tower wobble

My question is: **What is happening when a jenga block tower wobbles?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wobble is the result of creating an oscillating system.  At a perfect equilibrium, your tower would stand straight up and down, at rest, with a net force $\Sigma F$ equal to zero.  However, as you remove blocks, you are imparting a force on the tower, and disturbing the tower from equilibrium.  If that was the end of the story, your tower would continue to tilt until the center of gravity of the structure extended beyond the base, and then it would topple.

However, because you're just asking about *wobbles* in the tower, something more interesting is happening.  The fact that you disturb the tower, it begins to sway, *and then wobbles back to where it started* means that there must be some sort of restoring force that returns the tower to equilibrium.  This system then, by definition, is a harmonic oscillator.  The exact source of your restoring force is up for discussion, but is likely the result of the fact that your tower is not a single piece of material with perfectly fixed shape (called a rigid body) but instead is a collection of small wooden pieces that are capable of shifting individually.  As you suspected, it's likely interactions such as stretching and compression between individual pieces (tiny oscillations in and of themselves) that provide the effect of a restoring force to the entire tower.

Answer (score 0):

Informally, by the cumulative effects of friction when pulling out a piece (hence dragging it) and vibration of your hand when pulling out the piece (noticeable even with skilled players, however minute), you disturb the centre of gravity of the structure (by making the structure tilt),- making it subsequently topple because it is made of stacked pieces and not attached ones (Good ol' gravity here...)